# Ошибка в программе pygame

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame

pygame.init() 
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 300)) 
pygame.display.set_caption()

running = True 
while True: 

    pygame.display.update() 

    for event in pygame.event.get(): 
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
            running = False
            pygame.quit()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nickv/file Code/project/project_other/other/oth.py", line 9, in <module>
    pygame.display.update() # с помощью этой строчки мы все время обновляем наш экран
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pygame.error: video system not initialized
```

Что это за проблема и как ее исправить?

Comment: А вы попробуйте `update` на `flip` поменять.

Comment: не получилось, ошибка 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nickv/file Code/project/project_other/other/oth.py", line 5, in <module>
    pygame.display.set_caption()
TypeError: function missing required argument 'title' (pos 1)

Comment: Ну естественно. Это уже другая ошибка и к видеосистеме отношения она не имеет. (во-первых, в скобках посоветую бросить пока pygame и подучить питон, чтобы не думать по три часа над каждой мелочью). Во-вторых, вставьте между скобками в функции `title()` нужный вам заголовок и ошибка пропадет.

Answer (score 1):

[вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26767591/pygame-error-video-system-not-initialized) есть похожий вопрос.
мне помогла замена `pygame.quit()` на `exit()`

ну и как уже сказали выше `pygame.display.set_caption(<нужен заголовок сюда>)`